# Can I use one command to send multiple embed? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want to ask if it's possible to build a bot in Node.js (using Discord.js) with Visual Studio Code that if I send a single command, will reply with different embed messages.

It didn't work with command handler.

Comment: You can, but with webhooks, the other way with send canonly do one embeds, as for webhooks you can send 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, try using this:

```js
const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0xf7f7f8')
    .setTitle('Embed 1')
    .setDescription("First Embed")
    .addField("First Embed Field", "Text")
    
const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('0xf7f7f8')
    .setTitle('Embed 2')
    .setDescription("Second Embed")
    .addField("Second Embed Field", "Text")

message.channel.send({embed: embed1})
message.channel.send({embed: embed2})
```

There are probably better ways to go ahead and do this but this works perfectly!

Comment: the only fix this code needs is the field 


`const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
`
and not 

`const embed1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
`